# Cmake wont work - No current working directory

Tags: unix, path, compilation, cmake, directory

I am new to this stuff and I have been trying to fix another issue:

[Two OpenCV's are installed (with different versions) and I can't delete all traces of the past one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374868/two-opencvs-are-installed-with-different-versions-and-i-cant-delete-all-trac/34375674#34375674)

and I was suggested to do

```
cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = usr/local ..
```

which I did and cmake do not work now. When I try a simple "cmake .." I get

```
No current working directory
Aborted
```

How do I fix this? And how do I set cmake_prefix_path?

Comment: Check that you run `cmake` from existed directory (e.g., `cd .` should work).

Comment: Yeah that was it thanks a lot. I think I have deleted the current directory by accident via terminal, but I have no idea how. Anyway you can post your comment as answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CMake 2.8.10 (and older) generates error

> No current working directory

if current directory cannot be accessed(usually, deleted). This can be checked with command

```
cd .
```

Modern CMake (since 2.8.11) generates another error:

> Current working directory cannot be established.

See also [this bugreport](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13892).