# While running code I am getting "init done opengl support available" as oputput message but I am not getting output images

Tags: python, opencv

While running code I am getting "`init done opengl support available`"  as output message but I am not getting output images  i.e. erosion and dilation. How should I get it?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('threshold.png',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
dilation = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5))
cv2.imshow('erosion',erosion)    
cv2.imshow('dilation',dilation)    
print (erosion)
print (dilation)
```

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you are on linux and using OpenCV 3.X (mine was 3.2), here is how I solved it:

**1** Uninstall your current OpenCV version (you have how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276169/removing-all-installed-opencv-libs))

**2** Download OpenCV again:

> git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

**3** Use the following commands:

> mkdir release
>
> cd release
>
> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_TBB=OFF ..
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

It worked for me working under Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7. You can find more information at the official [webpage](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)