# How to completely uninstall opencv ubuntu?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-14.04, caffe, pycaffe

I am installing caffe and I think I screwed up my install by having multiple versions of OpenCV. Now i don't know what i did on my own but nothing seems to work right. So my safest bet is to do a complete utter uninstall of opencv. How do i do that help thanks ?

I would like to install python after that using conda

I followed this thread [Removing all installed OpenCV libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276169/removing-all-installed-opencv-libs/38217001#38217001)

although when i typed `$> sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;`

ubuntu still keeps asking me for permission to remove every file which is annoying. how do i tell ubuntu to remove it all ?

Comment: Maybe ask it on http://askubuntu.com/ to get more support

Answer (score 7):

If you installed OpenCV using CMake then there should be an `uninstall` file in the same location as the `install` file, just run `sudo make uninstall`.

Answer (score -1):

remove the -i option. -i option stands for "interactive"