# Python OpenCV 3.2 imshow() no image content with waitKey(0)!

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.2

I installed OpenCV3.2 + python3.6.1 from [this installation guide](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/). (For the paths needed in guide I typed:

---

**Edit**: I'm not sure, but I guess that I should install opencv under 3.6, not 3.6.1, please don't use my paths for your installation!

---

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin/libpython3.6.dylib
```

and

```
ls -d /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m/)
```

My testing code is completely the same as [the tutorial of OpenCV 3.2 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dc/d2e/tutorial_py_image_display.html), but the output screen show nothing but a title:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The result:

[image: OpenCV empty image window]
As the picture shown the content of the image is missing.

and it seems that it has something to do with my python, the icon is broken:

[image: broken python icon]

Please help me! I just want to use opencv for my school project...

---

Comment: The icon does not have anything to do with it, mine works fine and the icon still appears as such. Someone had the same problem the other day. I cannot find the question, but there wasn't an answer when I saw it, anyways. Do you have this same problem when running it as a script as opposed to in the interpreter? If `cv2` is importing fine (which it clearly is) then I don't think it's a problem with your install.

Comment: I'm very appreciated for your kind reply, big thanks for you first. I'm happy to know about the information you just provided. Now I'm just removing it, and re-installing it with python2.7 through Homebrew. Yes, I've tried both methods. :)@AlexanderReynolds

Comment: Hmm, I installed with the same tutorial with `python 3.6.1` also with `opencv 3.2.0`. But sure, give it a go in 2.7 and see what your results are. Did you test if `cv2.imwrite()` works?

Comment: No, I'm new to OpenCV actually. I just read the documentation/tutorial and followed it. I will try your suggestion after finishing the installation. :) @AlexanderReynolds

Answer (score 1):

If you just encounter the same problem, I can solve your problem. But you should take a look before you follow any further steps:

1. I will recommend you first **delete** OpenCV 3.2 from your mac.

   Don't know how to delele? Here are the steps:

   1. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9278502/7813604) first if you want to know what the following command do in details, then run the following command in your Terminal:

      ```
      $> sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
      ```
   2. > Please read every delete-checking message carefully, or you may delete some of your files containing "opencv" in filename, which may not related to OpenCV but **may be your personal files.**
   3. Your cv2.so will still alive somewhere in your disk, go checkout where it is with the following command in Terminal:

      ```
      $> ls -l /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
      ```

      In my case I found the cv2.so at `.../python3.6/...`, you should press 'tab' at `/usr/local/lib/python` then check out the `site-packages` folder for each python version (,which maybe you're about to re-install the OpenCV,) to search **cv2.so**. if you found it, delete it.
2. [Install OpenCV3.2 with Homebrew for Python2.7 / 3.6](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/). Just follow all the steps, and keep in mind that Homebrew is your best friend.

   Edit: The link works for both Python2.7 and 3.6.

Comment: If he's trying to install OpenCV with the *modern version* of Python, why would you suggest he install with the older version of Python? You can absolutely get OpenCV 3.2.0 working with Python 3.6.1 on a Mac.

Comment: Sorry for my misleading words. But actually the link I provided could work for both Python2.7 and Python3.6, and the link has step by step to let the reader setup for both. @AlexanderReynolds

Comment: Ah--you should edit the link text then, as it links to tutorials for 2.7 *and* 3. As an FYI, that was the tutorial the OP was using in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue but on the C++ API perspective. Credits go out to [mattmyne](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/8916).

> Window autosize was not working for macOS using cocoa. The window's image dimensions could not be found. This has been fixed by removing IP64 specific synthesize in window_cocoa.mm that was causing null reference for the window's contentView image property in cvShowImage (image reference was not linked to _image).

In a nutshell, OpenCV tried to support both 32 and 64-bit ObjC compilers but since Apple no longer supports 32-bit, some image synthesizing operations resulted in null references in 64-bit machines. More [info](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/8307)

To resolve this, locate the file *window_cocoa.mm*; if built from source it'll be in *opencv/modules/highgui/src*.

**Change this**

```
@implementation CVView
#if defined(__LP64__)
@synthesize image;
#else // 32-bit Obj-C does not have automatic synthesize
@synthesize image = _image;
#endif
```

**To this**

```
@implementation CVView
@synthesize image = _image;
```

Do the same thing for the `CVWindow` and `CVSlider` implementations to accommodate videos as well.

Recompile OpenCV and test out your code.