# Setting camera frame size for opencv is not responsive

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

Im using the following code to open webcam in my mac.

```
#define CAMERA_OUTPUT_WINDOW_NAME "camera"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    CvCapture *camCapture;
    int ret = 0;

    if (!(camCapture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY))) {
        cout << "Failed to capture from camera" << endl;

        ret = 1;

        goto exitCameraOpenFailed;
    }

    cout << "Camera opened successfully" << endl;

    cvNamedWindow(CAMERA_OUTPUT_WINDOW_NAME, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    IplImage *cameraFrame;
    cvSetCaptureProperty( camCapture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640 );

    cvSetCaptureProperty( camCapture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480 );

    while (true) {
        if ((cameraFrame = cvQueryFrame(camCapture))) {
            cvShowImage(CAMERA_OUTPUT_WINDOW_NAME, cameraFrame);
        }

        if (cvWaitKey(60) != -1) {
            cout << "Input" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Done" << endl;

    cvReleaseCapture(&camCapture);
    cvDestroyWindow(CAMERA_OUTPUT_WINDOW_NAME);
exitCameraOpenFailed:
    return ret;
}
```

But the output window frame resolution is too small. only the toolbar of the output frame is visible not the actual frame though i have set its size to 640x480.
How can I be able to sort this out?

I tried chaning the window_cocoa.mm file as

```
@implementation CVView
@synthesize image = _image;
```

But it has no effects on the final result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV imshow not displaying image in osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688437/opencv-imshow-not-displaying-image-in-osx)

Comment: Also, if this is c++, why is it using the C API of OpenCV?

Comment: aint sure where to use 
@ implementation CVView
@ synthesize image = _image;

Comment: i tried channging it in the mm file but it has no response