# How do I remove openCV

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ros

I am trying to remove opencv fully from my system. I was trying to learn ROS, while in tutorials I faced an issue. After creating empty workspace I invoke

`catkin_make`

It gives an common error, I searched and asked around in answers.ros

[here is the link of the question](https://answers.ros.org/question/369211/catkin_make-error-invoking-make-j8-l8-failed/)

I think I found out the problem was opencv libraries which I had build before installing ROS-Noetic, creating the error, I searched around how to remove opencv, but non of the answers totally remove opencv without removing my opencv names files.

Is there a common solution on how to remove opencv?

Ubuntu 20.04
ROS Noetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way if you installed opencv from source and still have the build directory, simply go there and call `make uninstall`. Another solution is to delete all opencv related files as you already know and suggested in many other similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276169/removing-all-installed-opencv-libs). You could also try to use synaptic package manager if you installed using a package.
I suggest for the future to install development libraries a custom folder, so it will be just a matter of deleting that folder if something goes wrong. In this way you can also have different opencv versions in your system, this is how I do.