# How can I uninstall an old version of OpenCV so that there are not conflicting files?

Tags: opencv, ros, catkin

I'm working on implementing OpenCV on my f1Tenth car and to do so I installed OpenCV 3.3.14 but it seems that the Nvidia Jetson Xavier that I'm working on already came with OpenCV 3.2 installed. I'm using ros to compile my workspace but when I try to catkin_make my workspace I get this error:

```
yellowcar@yellowcar-desktop:~/node_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/yellowcar/node_ws
Source space: /home/yellowcar/node_ws/src
Build space: /home/yellowcar/node_ws/build
Devel space: /home/yellowcar/node_ws/devel
Install space: /home/yellowcar/node_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/yellowcar/node_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/yellowcar/node_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Built target apriltags2
[ 28%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 28%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts
[ 28%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num
[ 28%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 28%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_scan_range
[ 28%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 28%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 28%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[ 28%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[ 28%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 28%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 28%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 28%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 28%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 28%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 28%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 28%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 28%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 28%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 28%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 28%] Built target _lab7_generate_messages_check_deps_test
[ 28%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 28%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 28%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target lab7_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 34%] Built target scan_match
[ 34%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 34%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 34%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 34%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[ 34%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 34%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 34%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[ 34%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[ 35%] Linking CXX executable /home/yellowcar/node_ws/devel/lib/testforopencv/sensortocv
[ 35%] Built target _apriltags2_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_AprilTagDetectionArray
[ 35%] Built target _apriltags2_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_AprilTagDetection
[ 35%] Built target _apriltags2_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_AnalyzeSingleImage
[ 40%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[ 42%] Built target wall_follow
[ 45%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
[ 47%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
[ 52%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_eus
[ 55%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 57%] Built target carReactive
[ 58%] Built target lab7_generate_messages_eus
[ 60%] Built target AEB
[ 62%] Built target lab7_generate_messages_py
[ 63%] Built target lab7_generate_messages_lisp
[ 64%] Built target lab7_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 66%] Built target Pure
[ 71%] Built target apriltags2_ros_generate_messages_eus
[ 73%] Built target apriltags2_ros_generate_messages_cpp
[ 76%] Built target apriltags2_ros_generate_messages_lisp
****/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4, needed by /home/yellowcar/third_party_folder/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.14, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.3.4, needed by /home/yellowcar/third_party_folder/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.14, may conflict with libopencv_core.so.3.2****
CMakeFiles/sensortocv.dir/src/imageColorFinder.cpp.o: In function `SensorTOCV::SensorTOCV()':
imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCVC2Ev[_ZN10SensorTOCVC5Ev]+0x2fc): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCVC2Ev[_ZN10SensorTOCVC5Ev]+0x324): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCVC2Ev[_ZN10SensorTOCVC5Ev]+0x38c): undefined reference to `cv::createTrackbar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int*, int, void (*)(int, void*), void*)'
imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCVC2Ev[_ZN10SensorTOCVC5Ev]+0x404): undefined reference to `cv::createTrackbar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int*, int, void (*)(int, void*), void*)'
imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCVC2Ev[_ZN10SensorTOCVC5Ev]+0x47c): undefined reference to `cv::createTrackbar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int*, int, void (*)(int, void*), void*)'
imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCVC2Ev[_ZN10SensorTOCVC5Ev]+0x4f4): undefined reference to `cv::createTrackbar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int*, int, void (*)(int, void*), void*)'
imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCVC2Ev[_ZN10SensorTOCVC5Ev]+0x56c): undefined reference to `cv::createTrackbar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int*, int, void (*)(int, void*), void*)'
CMakeFiles/sensortocv.dir/src/imageColorFinder.cpp.o:imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCVC2Ev[_ZN10SensorTOCVC5Ev]+0x5e4): more undefined references to `cv::createTrackbar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int*, int, void (*)(int, void*), void*)' follow
CMakeFiles/sensortocv.dir/src/imageColorFinder.cpp.o: In function `SensorTOCV::SensorTOCV()':
imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCVC2Ev[_ZN10SensorTOCVC5Ev]+0x63c): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
CMakeFiles/sensortocv.dir/src/imageColorFinder.cpp.o: In function `SensorTOCV::~SensorTOCV()':
imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCVD2Ev[_ZN10SensorTOCVD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::destroyWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/sensortocv.dir/src/imageColorFinder.cpp.o: In function `SensorTOCV::pose_callback(boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
imageColorFinder.cpp:(.text._ZN10SensorTOCV13pose_callbackERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN8tf2_msgs10TFMessage_ISaIvEEEEE[_ZN10SensorTOCV13pose_callbackERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN8tf2_msgs10TFMessage_ISaIvEEEEE]+0x19c): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
testforopencv/CMakeFiles/sensortocv.dir/build.make:143: recipe for target '/home/yellowcar/node_ws/devel/lib/testforopencv/sensortocv' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/yellowcar/node_ws/devel/lib/testforopencv/sensortocv] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3583: recipe for target 'testforopencv/CMakeFiles/sensortocv.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [testforopencv/CMakeFiles/sensortocv.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 78%] Built target apriltags2_ros_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 84%] Built target apriltags2_ros_generate_messages_py
[ 84%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Do I need to uninstall the old version of OpenCV and if so how do I go about doing that? Let me know if there is anything else anyone would need to solve this

Comment: You may try `make uninstall` in the directory where you called `make install` for building OpenCV.

Comment: @Burak The issue is that I need 3.4.14, the version that I just installed, not the old version of 3.2

Comment: Then you may try [uninstalling all OpenCV libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276169/removing-all-installed-opencv-libs) and installing the version you want again.