# ImportError: libopencv_hdf.so.4.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, opencv

This question has been asked many times here. but I tried all the answers so far but nothing worked. this is the code I am trying to run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
from sensor_msgs import msg
import cv2
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError


def takes_data_from_camera():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('TestOps/Camera', String, queue_size=10) 
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    video_bridge = "AKASH"
    video_out = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(video_out, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    video_bridge = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(gray, "passthrough")
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pub.publish(video_bridge)
    
    while (True):
        cv2.imshow('frame',video_out)
        #ret,frame = video.read()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
            #video.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bridge = CvBridge()
    rospy.init_node('Server',anonymous = True)
    takes_data_from_camera()
```

when I run the code I get the following error.

```
/bin/python3 /home/akash-j/catkin_ws/src/test_package/src/py-server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akash-j/catkin_ws/src/test_package/src/py-server.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 112, in bootstrap
    import cv2
ImportError: libopencv_hdf.so.4.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To give more details about the problem I faced a problem while installing OpenCV and I have installed it multiple times. First, my OpenCV on python was working fine. then I tried to install OpenCV for c++. using the link https://learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu-16-04/. even though i could not install some of the step2 on the install os libraries i skipped and followed the steps till step 5. then i could not figure the step2 "how to use opencv on c++". so just stopped there and came back to my python file.now i could not even import opencv on python also.

Comment: Any reason you deleted the [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69172131/removing-opencv-form-ubuntu) and posted a new one?

Comment: it was not clear

Comment: Then you should edit it instead of creating a new one.

Comment: sorry my bad, i try to avoid this later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically as you said you tried installing opencv for c++ and after getting errors you came back...
Try removing opencv completely from your system
[This resource may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9278502/7357716). Afterwards install opencv using pip. You can install opencv in a virtual environment to keep both libraries aside. If you have such a usecase.

```
pip3 install opencv-python  #for python3

pip install opencv-python   #for python2
```

Reference for [installing opencv in python](https://data-flair.training/blogs/install-opencv-on-ubuntu/)

Then try importing the library in your code and execute your code.
Your code will execute successfully and then try installing opencv separately for c++.

And for install opencv for c++, you can refer to this [resource](http://techawarey.com/programming/install-opencv-c-c-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-step-by-step-guide/) also.

Comment: i almost removed all the files named opencv. some i could not. it shows the following command.
find: ‘/run/user/1001/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1001/gvfs’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/usr/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv': Is a directory

Comment: i have followed the steps you mentioned and it worked well. I have trying to figure it out for 3 days. thanks for the help